# Does this sound right to you?

Tags: riddle

What is the missing integer in this sequence?

9, ___ , 5

And who is this?  5, 6

---

I'd give you another clue but it's time to work!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the missing integer is

> 2

Because this references

> The song and film "9 to 5"

Who is this? (5,6)

> DOLLY PARTON

Explaining the Title

> 2 sound like "to" (at least the way it's sung).

It's time to work!

> Work is mentioned at the end and "9 to 5" represents normal office working hours.